# MySQL db import error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I got an error 1064 when importin a database from my old host into my new host through php myadmin.

Can you please help me to resolve this?

> SQL query:

```
 forum_hrhokej1.sql100777 0 0 1635074240 12165000252 10020 0-- -- Database: `bmikic_hrhokej` -- -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table `phpbb_acl_groups` -- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpbb_acl_groups` ( `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `forum_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `auth_option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `auth_role_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `auth_setting` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',[...]
```

> MySQL said:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'forum_hrhokej1.sql' at line 1
```

> Full Query

```
--
-- Database: `bmikic_hrhokej.sql`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `phpbb_acl_groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpbb_acl_groups` (
 `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `forum_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `auth_option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `auth_role_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `auth_setting` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
KEY `auth_opt_id` (`auth_option_id`),
KEY `auth_role_id` (`auth_role_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

--
-- Dumping data for table `phpbb_acl_groups`
```

Comment: the create table statement looks fine, are you sure you trying to import it the right way?

Comment: Try leaving only the parts that are to build the tables (CREATE, INSERT), remove comments and DB settings (COLLATIONS, ...).

Comment: I have a database from old phpbb forum and I am trying to import it through phpmyadmin. Logged on to my cpanel - phpmyadmin - import. Seems like pretty straightforward thing to do but I can't get it to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let all of you know, the problem was in phpmyadmin.

Database was too large, I managed to import it through ssh without a problem.

Comment: The error you get clearly complaints about `forum_hrhokej1.sql` and it's normal: `forum_hrhokej1.sql100777 0 0 1635074240 12165000252 10020 0` does not even resemble SQL code and everything else is commented out with `-- `.

Comment: I managed to import the same sql db from ssh, apparently phpmyadmin was doing something wrong

Comment: Probably not the same query. You've posted 2 queries. The error belongs to the first one, which is clearly corrupted.